# How to read the first value in array in json format using powershell

Tags: arrays, json

I have a below data which is stored in a variable **$data**
[Content in $data variable is shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmPHr.png)

I need to export only specific fields like number,state,priority,assigned_to,opened_by,assignment_group.For the fields which are in array format,i need only the display_value to be exported to excel sheet.

I tried like below:
$data | Select number,state,priority,assigned_to,opened_by,assignment_group | Export-Excel -path "xxx"
Output:
I got blank outputs for the fields which are in array format.
[Output is shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbPc6.png)

Expected Output:
[Expected output is shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAb3O.png)

Any help on this is much appreciated

Comment: Objects not arrays.

Comment: ok,can you help to get the result as expected?

Comment: You'd have to do calculated properties like `$data | select @{n='assigned_to';e={$_.assigned_to.display_value}}`  Showing the text is preferred to screen shots.